# Does $g$ always normalize $H \cap H^g$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be any group, $H$ a subgroup, $g$ an element of $G$ and $H^g:=g^{-1}Hg$ the conjugate of $H$ by $g$. Is it true that $$g\in N_G(H\cap H^g)?$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

As a counterexample take $G$ to be the split extension of an elementary abelian group of order $16$ by a cyclic group of order $4$ with this action
$$
G=\left\langle x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4, g\mid x_i^2=1, x_i x_j=x_j x_i,   g^4=1, x_i^g=x_{i+1 \mod 4}\right\rangle
$$
and let $H=\langle x_1,x_2\rangle$.

Then $H\cap H^g=\langle x_2\rangle$ is not normalised by $g$.

Comment: The same idea would work with an elementary group of order $8$ with an acting element of order $3$.

Comment: Indeed @DerekHolt, I suppose I just wanted to give myself a bit of elbow room! And I suppose I show the answer is "not even in a $p$-group".